# Dynamic Arrow Positioning on Skobbler for Android

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I have a custom SKCalloutView on Android, but the tail is following the marker, behaviour that I don't want.

Looking at the documentation for iOS i found that there they have the method "dynamicArrowPositioning", but was unable to find a similar method on the Android version of the API.

Does anyone know how to disable the dynamic arrow positioning?

Answer (score 1):

You’ll find in the SKCalloutView class the "showAtLocation" method- if you want to show the callout on map at the specified coordinates (showing or hiding the tail)
http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKCalloutView.html#showAtLocation

Or "redraw"-if you only want to modify view position and resize it 
http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKCalloutView.html#redraw()

Comment: The showAtLocation and redraw does not solve my problem. I already showed the CalloutView, I want the equivalent in Android of iOS's "dynamicArrowPositioning" that locks the popup and the marker at the same position even when the user moves the map.